# What is the concept of wormholes?

Tags: black-hole, universe, space, time, wormhole

My main queries for now I guess: What is the theory behind wormholes? What is the possibility and likeliness of their existence based on scientific analysis, not conspiracy theories? What is the physical nature of wormholes? Do they connect black holes and white holes? Is there some sort of link between wormholes and time travel? Feel free to add more info

Comment: What's your prior research? Have you tried reading about wormholes on Wikipedia? Half of your questions will already be answered there...

Comment: Duplicates: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/158/what-is-a-wormhole https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/22344/are-wormholes-even-possible https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/how-could-we-observe-a-wormhole